# iOS: Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have several view controllers in separate XIBs. My application is universal, so they have ~ipad and ~iphone added to their names. All of them are working -  except one (LoginViewController~ipad.xib). When calling `initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` it's throwing the exception `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle'`. I made sure that:

- xib name is correct
- File's Owner in XIB is of correct class
- file is added in BuildPhases->Copy Bundle Resources
- Target Membership is checked in File Inspector

I also tried:

- cleaning the project
- closing and re-opening Xcode
- removing the file from the project and adding it again

The exception is thrown only for ~iPad xib and only for this view controller. Any ideas what I might be missing?

[edit]
The solution turned out to be pretty simple. The XIB name I passed to `init` contained some magical, invisible character at the end. I started using `NSStringFromClass` and everything works fine.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle'

Comment: Have you checked the File's owner custom class name and view has connected to outlet?

Comment: @Nagendra like I wrote, File's Owner in XIB is of correct class, and yes, the view is connected

Comment: Removed derived data and then try.

Comment: @Tirth that didn't work

Comment: I'm guessing it should give you the name of the XIB it's trying to load in the error?